# Why "crq" package gives different result (except the coefficients) for the same data set?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, quantile

```
library(survival)
library(quantreg)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1245)
n=1000
b0=1
b1=0.5
x<-runif(n,0,5)  
w<-rnorm(n,0,1)
realtimes<-exp(b0+b1*x+w) #real time
v<-rnorm(n,0,1)
censtimes<-exp(1+1*x+v)
Time<-pmin(realtimes,censtimes) #observed time
Status<-as.numeric(censtimes > realtimes) 
Status1<-(censtimes > realtimes)
d<-data.frame(x=x,Time=Time,Status=Status,realtimes=realtimes,censtimes=censtimes,Status1)

w1<-crq(Surv(log(Time),Status1,type="right")~x,data =d, method = "Portnoy")
Model<-summary.crq(w1,taus=0.5,alpha=0.05,se="boot")
```

```
Result:
tau: [1] 0.5

Coefficients:
            Value    Lower Bd Upper Bd Std Error T Value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.94262  0.67825  1.20878  0.13534   6.96469  0.00000
x            0.52502  0.41431  0.58942  0.04467  11.75257  0.00000
```

When I run the code again I get different result for this data set. Lower bound,upper bound, SE are different. I don't know why. It should be the same.

```
tau: [1] 0.5 (Another result)

Coefficients:
            Value    Lower Bd Upper Bd Std Error T Value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.94262  0.75988  1.29875  0.13747   6.85700  0.00000
x            0.52502  0.40507  0.60013  0.04976  10.55080  0.00000
```

Comment: Did you use the same seed on the different run (as `se="boot"` would suggest that errors are being calculated by bootstrap sampling)?

Comment: Can you check please, when I run the code in your question, the line of code with `summary.crq`  gives an *Error in B$A[1, , , drop = TRUE] : incorrect number of dimensions*

Comment: I have used the same seed. I don't get any error. I have checked it. I have used the package "crq" and the default is se="boot". I do not know what's happening here @user20650

Comment: Ummay; sorry, the source of the error was my quantreg version. Your code runs okay. However, when i set the seed before each run of `summary.crq` then I get the same results

Answer (score 1):

Because `summary.crq` uses a bootstrap method to calculate standard errors, we should *not* expect the output to be the same each time. Let us set a random seed and examine the output:

```r
set.seed(12345)

summary.crq(w1, taus = 0.5, alpha = 0.05, se = "boot")
#> 
#> tau: [1] 0.5
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Value    Lower Bd Upper Bd Std Error T Value  Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)  0.94262  0.77930  1.29924  0.13264   7.10661  0.00000
#> x            0.52502  0.43411  0.62189  0.04791  10.95924  0.00000
```

Now if we run the command again, we get different results, because *we have used the random number generator, which automatically changes the seed.*

```r
summary.crq(w1, taus = 0.5, alpha = 0.05, se = "boot")
#> 
#> tau: [1] 0.5
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Value    Lower Bd Upper Bd Std Error T Value  Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)  0.94262  0.74946  1.27719  0.13463   7.00167  0.00000
#> x            0.52502  0.42738  0.60686  0.04579  11.46639  0.00000
```

If we want identical results to our first ones, we need to put the random seed back to where it was:

```r
set.seed(12345)
summary.crq(w1, taus = 0.5, alpha = 0.05, se = "boot")
#> 
#> tau: [1] 0.5
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Value    Lower Bd Upper Bd Std Error T Value  Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)  0.94262  0.77930  1.29924  0.13264   7.10661  0.00000
#> x            0.52502  0.43411  0.62189  0.04791  10.95924  0.00000
```

Note that these third results are identical to the first results.

<sup>Created on 2023-07-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>